# Pretty URLs - Dot Causing Error

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, pretty-urls

EDIT: This issue was mostly solved by an answer below, but it also raised a new question. If I remove "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=F" from the .htaccess file, I am again redirected to stock.com/index.php?page=index.php if I make a request to stock.com/register. I could just accept that it needs to be there, but I'm trying to understand why removal of this line of code causes this behavior. I get that it is there to allow visitors access to actual files such as images, but I don't get how it is also related to a redirect/reroute of a URL such as stock.com/register. If anyone could explain that I would really appreciate it.

Trying to get a pretty URLs to work for a simple MVC site I'm developing locally on Wampserver, just for learning purposes. I have the following .htaccess code setup so that any URL request is routed back to the index.php controller, which serves different content based on the $_GET value of 'page'.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=D
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=F
RewriteRule ^([-\w.]+)$ index.php\?page=$1 [R=302,L]
```

I have it set to R=302 just so I can see where it's redirecting me. The hostname I've set it up to work at is stock.com. If I go to stock.com, this works fine. But if I try to visit stock.com/register, I'm redirected to stock.com/index.php?page=index.php. If I take the dot out of the regex, this all works fine, but then I'm unable to have page/file names with dots in them. Not necessary, but I'm doing this for learning purposes, so I'd like to know what the solution is here. I've tried both escaping the dot and not. Thanks!

Comment: `.` (dot) means any a character except newlines. You probably mean a literal `\.`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried it both ways and get the same result. From what I read, a dot is not a metacharacter inside a character class, and so doesn't need to be escaped. Is that wrong?

Comment: No, that is correct. My bad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some syntax issues. Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([-\w.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. If you don't mind and just for learning purposes, could you explain why the 2 RewriteCond's above prevents the behavior I outlined initially (redirection to stock.com/index.php?page=index.php) I'm  just having trouble in my mind seeing how the 2 are connected. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes sure I can explain. Two `RewriteCond` lines skip this rewrite rule if request is or a for a valid file (`!-f`)or directory (`!-d`). Rewrite engine runs these rules for as long as there is a matching rule. So without these 2 conditions when rewrite rule runs again it rewrites to `index.php?page=index.php`. You can see you had some rules but it wasn't working due to wrong syntax. But I didn't understand why did you remove acceptance mark from a working answer.

Comment: I guess I'm just still not getting it. If I type in stock.com/lecture, the ^([-\w.]+)$ should match and capture the 'lecture' part of the URL, then rewrite/reroute to stock.com/index.php?page=lecture. I don't get why index.php is getting selected/captured, when it is no part of the original entered URL. At least this is how it seems it should be to me. Why is rewrite rule running again without those 2 conditional rules? And I will again accept your answer as the correct one, I just wanted to leave it open for a bit to get more feedback from others. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And I still am not getting why the RewriteCond's affect any of this if the entered URL is stock.com/lecture, which is neither a file or directory. Lol, sorry if I'm being really dense. It's just not making sense to me.

Comment: I have never failed to respond to any questions here but removing acceptance from a working answer just to get queries answered doesn't appear right approach to me. Anyway that is your decision. Coming back to your question it seems you don't realize how `mod_rewrite` works. As I wrote earlier also that **Rewrite engine runs these rules again and again as long as there is a matching rule.** After 1st rewrite since `index.php` matches `^([-\w.]+)$` regex again therefore you get wrong results. See the picture in this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html to understand more

Comment: Sorry about removing acceptance, my bad. Thank you for the explanation and it's making more sense to me. I read the info at the link you posted, and the chart it had helped. I apologize again, but what I'm just not getting is that if the URL I enter is stock.com/lecture, why is index.php a match if it's not part of the URL? Your link may have explained this, just not in a way I can understand yet. Thanks again.

Comment: If you take out dot form your regex e.g.: `^([-\w]+)$` then `index.php` won't be matched and then rule will not fire for `index.php` See after first rewrite URI became `/index.php` and it still matches given regex: `^([-\w.]+)$` therefore rewrite rule executes again matching `index.php`

Comment: So the first time rewrite executes, it rewrites the URL to stock.com/index.php?page=register. Then it runs through again and matches index.php and so rewrites the URL to stock.com/index.php?page=index.php. If that is correct, I think that was the part I was missing. I didn't realize that the second time the rewrite rule executes that it was executing on the newly rewritten-to URL. I was thinking it was running through stock.com/register again. Thanks for all your replies!

Comment: Yes that it true. When it runs 2nd time then `REQUEST_URI` is `/index.php` and `QUERY_STRING` is `page=register` Your rule is only matching `REQUEST_URI` and it matches `index.php`